# Why do my two encrypted hex strings decrypt to the same string?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, des

I am trying to write a simple mcrypt tripledes encrypt and decrypt function (code below taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php and modified).

```
<?php
class Cipher {
    private $securekey, $iv;
    private $val;
    function __construct($textkey) {
        $this->securekey = $textkey;                            
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(24);
    }

    function decrypt_hex($input){
        $bin = hex2bin($input);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt("tripledes", $this->securekey, $bin, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
    }

    function encrypt_hex($input){
        $this->val = mcrypt_encrypt("tripledes", $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv);
        return strtoupper(bin2hex($this->val));
    }
}

$cipher = new Cipher('123456789012345678901234');

$text = "2BF8F771E6FAE998AAE0C126B3FDD1994046C0498645E35D4B97BD1710125FFD";
echo "Decrypting ===== $text<br/>";
$dec = $cipher->decrypt_hex($text);
echo "Decrypted = $dec<br/>";

$text = "2BF8F771E6FAE998AAE0C126B3FDD1994046C0498645E35D72FD337F5B6B334B";
echo "Decrypting ===== $text<br/>";
$dec = $cipher->decrypt_hex($text);
echo "Decrypted = $dec<br/>";

?>
```

However, I find that the same string can be decrypted from two different encrypted hex strings (cases shown at the end of the code).

1. Is this normal?
2. How many of such strings exists? How can I find?
3. There seem to be some hidden characters at the end of first decrypted string. They do not show up in html (<s>probably visible in the edit text mode</s>, cleaned up by html sanitizer :( ). Is that the difference?

Output of above script in PHP 5.6.8:

```
Decrypting ===== 2BF8F771E6FAE998AAE0C126B3FDD1994046C0498645E35D4B97BD1710125FFD
Decrypted = Beli IM3 085728317777 30000
Decrypting ===== 2BF8F771E6FAE998AAE0C126B3FDD1994046C0498645E35D72FD337F5B6B334B
Decrypted = Beli IM3 085728317777 30000
```

Answer (score 3):

You've only changed the end of the ciphertext. This holds the last block of encrypted plaintext. However, usually the plaintext doesn't end on a block boundary. In that case PHP will perform zero padding until a block boundary is reached. These zero bytes are removed by the `trim` function (you should use `rtrim` and only remove `\0` bytes).

Now if you change the bytes of the last block then the decrypt will result in random bytes. That block may start - by chance - with the same characters, followed by any other - possibly unprintable - characters. In that case the string printed on screen may display the same.

You should really:

- use AES (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`);
- perform PKCS#7 compatible padding;
- use CBC mode encryption with a random IV;
- prefix that IV to the ciphertext;
- add an authentication tag (using HMAC-SHA-1);
- possibly encode the IV + ciphertext + tag.

Answer (score 1):

They are different, try this: `var_dump($dec1 === $dec2);` which returns **false**.

Also `echo strlen($dec1);` returns **32** and `echo strlen($dec2);` returns **27**.

Update:
Found out, that they have different encodings. Thus they have different sizes:
`var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($dec1));` returns string(5) "**UTF-8**". When `var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($dec2));` returns string(5) "**ASCII**".

Comment: Hi, you are right! Isn't it strange that the printable text is the same?

Comment: No, it is not that strange. The output does not include any special character. Just different encodings. ;)